# Extend a tensor of sequences so that every sequence is prepended

Tags: pytorch

I am having a tensor of 3 sequences where every sequence has length 2 and consists of vectors of size 2:

```
import torch
t = torch.Tensor([[[11,12],[21,22]], [[31,32],[41,42]], [[51,52],[61,62]]])
>>> t
tensor([[[11., 12.],
         [21., 22.]],

        [[31., 32.],
         [41., 42.]],

        [[51., 52.],
         [61., 62.]]])
```

So `t` has the structure `t[batch, sequencePos, dataPos]`. How can I extend every sequence so that it is prepended by a new element `[01, 02]` (sequence have then length 3) so that I get:

```
tensor([[[01., 02.],
         [11., 12.],             
         [21., 22.]],

        [[01., 02.],
         [31., 32.]
         [41., 42.]],

        [[01., 02.],
         [51., 52.],
         [61., 62.]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to concatenate two tensors on `axis=1`, the first one being `t`:

```
 >>> t
tensor([[[11., 12.],
         [21., 22.]],

        [[31., 32.],
         [41., 42.]],

        [[51., 52.],
         [61., 62.]]])
```

The second one is an arrangement:

```
>>> arr = torch.arange(t.size(-1))
tensor([0, 1])
```

However, we first need to broadcast it to the correct shape using [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html) and [`torch.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html):

```
>>> arr = arr.reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(len(t), 1, 1)
tensor([[[0, 1]],

        [[0, 1]],

        [[0, 1]]])
```

At this point, `arr.shape` is `torch.Size([3, 1, 4])`.

We are set for concatenating `arr` and `t` together, either with [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html):

```
>>> torch.cat((arr, t), dim=1)
```

or more elegantly with [`torch.hstack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.hstack.html):

```
>>> torch.hstack((arr, t))
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
         [11., 12.],
         [21., 22.]],

        [[ 0.,  1.],
         [31., 32.],
         [41., 42.]],

        [[ 0.,  1.],
         [51., 52.],
         [61., 62.]]])
```

Notice how this implementation will work with any 3-dimensional input. In the following example `t` has three columns instead of two:

```
>>> t
tensor([[[11., 12., 13.],
         [21., 22., 23.]],

        [[31., 32., 33.],
         [41., 42., 43.]],

        [[51., 52., 53.],
         [61., 62., 63.]]])

>>> arr = torch.arange(t.size(-1)).reshape(1, 1, -1).repeat(len(t), 1, 1)
>>> torch.cat((arr, t), dim=1)
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
         [11., 12., 13.],
         [21., 22., 23.]],

        [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
         [31., 32., 33.],
         [41., 42., 43.]],

        [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
         [51., 52., 53.],
         [61., 62., 63.]]])
```

---

This can even be generalized to n-dimensional tensors. You just have to take care of the `reshape` and `repeat` calls where the number of arguments depends on the number of dimensions.

```
>>> ones = (1,)*(t.ndim-1)
>>> arr = torch.arange(t.size(-1)).reshape(*ones, -1).repeat(len(t), *ones)
>>> torch.cat((arr, t), dim=-2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves my problem. I am just wondering, why this is so complicated in PyTorch, in numpy the same can be achieved by only once invocation to ```numpy.insert```.